# How to pass Click event handler as a parameter to another sub?

Tags: vb.net, events, parameters

In VB.Net I’m writing a program but I don’t know how to pass Click event handler as a parameter to another sub and how to call it from there. Can I do that? If yes, how?

E.g.: I have the following code. On two forms I have 1 ListView and 1 Button. If I press the button, it calls the click event of the button. In addition, if I press CTRL+P in the ListView, it calls the same event. I do it on both forms.

On form1:

```
Private Sub MyPrintButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyPrintButton1.Click
    ' Print MyListView1 data...
End Sub


Private Sub MyListView1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyListView1.KeyUp
    ' CTRL+P = Print
    If e.Modifiers = Keys.Control AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.P Then
        e.Handled = True
        MyPrintButton1_Click(sender, e)
    End If
End Sub
```

On form2:

```
Private Sub MyPrintButton2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyPrintButton2.Click
    ' Print MyListView2 data...
End Sub

Private Sub MyListView2_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyListView2.KeyUp
    ' CTRL+P = Print
    If e.Modifiers = Keys.Control AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.P Then
        e.Handled = True
        MyPrintButton2_Click(sender, e)
    End If
End Sub
```

I want to create only one sub in a different (common) file and want to call that passing the variables sender & e, and the event handler of the two Click events.

In this case the two KeyUp events would be the same, only the name of the passed event would be different:

On form1:

```
Private Sub MyListView1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyListView1.KeyUp
    ' Handle
    AllListViews_KeyUp(sender, e, AddressOf MyPrintButton1_Click)
End Sub
```

On form2:

```
Private Sub MyListView2_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyListView2.KeyUp
    ' Handle
    AllListViews_KeyUp(sender, e, AddressOf MyPrintButton2_Click)
End Sub
```

And the common sub would be similar like this:

```
Public Sub AllListViews_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs, PassedPrintButton_Click As ???? Of(????))
    ' CTRL+P = Print
    If e.Modifiers = Keys.Control AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.P Then
        e.Handled = True
        PassedPrintButton_Click(sender2, e2 ????)
    End If
End Sub
```

So: How do I need to pass the events as parameter and how to call the event? When I call the PassedPrintButton_Click event, how can I pass its own sender and e parameters (sender2, e2)? And how and where can I declare them?)

And, when I pass the address of MyPrintButton1_Click and addressMyPrintButton2_Click, from where will the sub know the click event’s sender and e parameters?

Thanks is advance.

Comment: You don't call an event handler directly.  If you want a `Button` to raise its `Click` event, call its `PerformClick` method.  Other than that, if you have code that you want executed when a `Button` is clicked and some other time too, put that code in its own method and then call it from the `Click` event handler of the `Button` and from wherever else you need to call it too.

Comment: i don't know if it's "byref" is what you were looking for.. make sure you read about that even thought jmcilhinney's solution would solve your issue in this particular situation..